# How do I access bound Polymer data and use it in script?

Tags: javascript, data-binding, polymer, polymer-1.0

I'm using `<firebase-document>` to get data from Firebase. I'm binding the data to `{{poster}}`. I then use that ID to show details of the poster object using its keys. For example, `{{poster.name}}` shows the name of the poster. I want to now use that `{{poster.name}}` in a script. When I `console.log(this.poster.name)`, I get an `undefined` error. How do I access the `{{poster}}` bound data?

Here is my element:

```js
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/plastr-poster/plastr-poster.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymerfire/firebase-document.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/app-metadata/app-metadata.html">
<link rel="import" href="shared-styles.html">

<dom-module id="my-details">
  <template>
    <style include="shared-styles">
      :host {
        display: block;
      }
    </style>

    <app-route
      route="{{route}}"
      pattern="/:poster_id"
      data="{{routeData}}"
      tail="{{subroute}}">
    </app-route>

    <firebase-document
      id="firebaseDoc"
      path="/posters/[[routeData.poster_id]]"
      data="{{poster}}">
    </firebase-document>
    <app-metadata></app-metadata>

    <div class="poster_board">
      <a href="./[[routeData.poster_id]]">
        <plastr-poster id="poster" name="[[poster.name]]" location=[[poster.location]] poster="[[poster.poster]]" date="[[poster.date]]"></plastr-poster>
      </a>
    </div>
  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'my-details',
      ready: function() {
        this.fire('app-metadata', {
          title: this.poster.name,
          description: "things to do in your 'hood",
          keywords: 'events, posters, local, music, dance, art'
        });
        console.log(this.poster.name);
      },
      attached: function() {
        // this will create the singleton element if it has not been created yet
        Polymer.AppMetadata.requestAvailability();
      },
      properties: {
        prop1: {
          type: String,
          value: 'plastr-app',
        },
      }
  });

  </script>
</dom-module>
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your `ready` handler is trying to access `this.poster.name`, but `this.poster` would not have been populated yet by `<firebase-document>`. I would use an [observer](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/observers#complex-observers) on `poster.name` like this:

```
Polymer({
  // ...

  observers: ['_fireMetadataEvent(poster.name)'],

  _fireMetadataEvent: function(posterName) {
    if (posterName) {
      this.fire('app-metadata', {
        title: posterName,
        // ...
      });
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: Thanks! Works perfect. Thank you so much!

Comment: @dnvn No problem :)